# What is the best way to manage a very complex model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have the following entity which I use as model in my asp.net mvc app

```
public class USERS{
      public int PK { get; set; } // Primary key
      public string Username { get; set; }
      public string Password { get; set; }
      public int FK_PEOPLE { get; set; } //Foreign key to table PEOPLE
      public PEOPLE Person { get; set; } // The very PEOPLE property  
      ...10-15 additional fields, including List<SomeEntity>, etc.
}
```

And here is the class PEOPLE

```
public class PEOPLE{
       public int PK { get; set; } // Primary key
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Surname { get; set; } 
}
```

When I send a USERS object to my View, then I get all the data and I display everything in a form. Everything's fine. I can see all the data. To make things more fancy, I display the PEOPLE properties in a Partial View.

The problems appear when I get back the model in my HttpPost Action. I managed (using HiddenFor) to get USERS.PK and USERS.FK_PEOPLE but USERS.Person entity is always null.

I tried [Bind(Prefix = "USERS")] but it didn't help. Even if a sollution like that worked, am I supposed to do this for every single property in my model? Do I really have to manually fix all the bindings for each and every property? This would take forever.. There has to be a better way to get my model complete, at least as I sent it in the HttpGet Action..

Gratefull for all help I can get :)

PS: I know, there are plenty of threads about Model binding but I don't think I have a binding problem. I want to find a way to "avoid" the binding.

Comment: If its not binding then your view is wrong and you **do** have a _binding problem_. Show it! (and using a partial will not work unless you pass the `HtmlFieldPrefix` as `additionalViewData`. Use a `EditorTemplate`)

Comment: But do you really want to post this whole model back?

Comment: I probably would create a ViewModel that only had the properties you need to show in somewhat of a flat view so you don't have too many nested complex objects.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that your view is outputting?

Comment: @thiag0
Red frame is the PEOPLE entities, generated in partial view:
[img]http://i.imgur.com/Ew79lFJ.png

Here is the HTML:
[img]http://i.imgur.com/2dcs3Ue.png
Not sure if that helps

Comment: Guys, maybe I have understood the whole MVC thing wrong.. I have already my "Model" and I wanted to use it as it was. I don't think it's elegant and time efficient to recreate other models only because asp.net mvc "can't handle" it.. But is that really so? Or is there another way to send a model to a view, let the user edit ONLY A FEW properties and then get back the same model, just with updated data??? This is my question!

Comment: @Nikos, You do not need to create other models (although if these are data models, then you should be creating view models). You need to generate the view correctly. But you have not shown it so no one can guess what mistakes you have made. And read the first comment again.

Comment: @StephenMuecke These are indeed data models, I don't even have view models. I hoped I could live with my data models. What do you want me to show? The controller? The view?

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @StephenMuecke

I was using my PartialView wrong. The sollution was to use it as an EditorTemplate.
So, this works:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PERSON)
    </div>
```

This doesn't work:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/PartialViews/Person/Index.cshtml", Model.PERSON); }
    </div>
```

Finally, all I had to do was to rename my PartialView to PERSON.cshtml and move it under ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/

Thanks a lot!